# Escape / Ignore special characters in HAML attributes

Tags: javascript, haml

I'm using HAML to make html templates but am having a problem in writing attributes which will be replaced with JavaScript string templating.

The line in question looks like this:

```
%div{:class => "<%= from_class %>"}
```

HAML tries to encode the <%= %> tags:

```
<div class="&lt;%= from_class %&gt;">
```

I don't want that to happen in this case... Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the next version of Haml (3.1), there will be an `:escape_attrs` option that you'll be able to set to `false` to prevent this. You'll also be able to pass `--no-escape-attrs` on the command line. To use this right now, you can install the alpha version with `gem install haml --prerelease`.

Comment: May be useful for newbies (like me) needing this tip: **1. Add this to your Gemfile:** `gem 'haml', '>=3.1.1'` - **2. Run** `bundle install` - **3. Add this to your `config/environment.rb` file:** `Haml::Template.options[:escape_attrs] = false` - **4. Finally restart your server.** You can also find the documentation for this option [here](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#escape_attrs-option)

Answer (score 1):

As @Natalie Weizenbaum  and @rchampourlier state above, put this in an initializer

config/initializers/haml.rb

```
Haml::Template.options[:escape_attrs] = false
```

Also note that because haml determines it's own order of classes:

This, because of the spaces:

```
.input-group-addon{class: "<%= field_name %>"}
```

Will render to this which doesn't work for templates:

```
<div class="%> <%= field_name input-group-addon">
```

The solution is to move the dot class (.input-group-addon) into the class: text:

```
%div{class: "<%= field_name %> input-group-addon"}
```

Which will render what we want:

```
<div class="<%= field_name %> input-group-addon">
```

It may work for you to use no spaces (<%=field_name%>) but if you need any template logic that requires spaces, bring the .dot-class into the text...

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406162/192221) answer, use a separate ruby variable with html_safe:

```
- foo = "&#x0026".html_safe
%a(href='/posts' data-icon=foo aria-hidden='true')
```