# How could I escape a & in Haml so that it compiles to & instead of &amp;? (Haml noob)

Tags: haml

I am trying to use the Icomoon icon font with Haml and can't seem to find a way to escape the `&` so that it stays just an `&` instead of `&amp;`.

The Icomoon font allows you to use HTML entities with a data-icon="" attribute. Works smooth as butter in HTML and even in a Haml file if I just do a straight HTML link.

However, since I'm learning Haml I thought I'd see if anyone on here would like to recommend the best way to approach this.

Here's a sample of what happens.

This is the original Haml:

```
%a(href='/posts' data-icon="&#x0026" aria-hidden='true')
```

This is how it compiles:

```
<a aria-hidden='true' data-icon='&amp;#x0026' href='/posts'>
```

This is how it needs to compile for the icon font to work:

```
<a aria-hidden='true' data-icon='&#x0026' href='/posts'>
```

and here is a codepen where you can see how the icon renders due to the amp; addition: http://codepen.io/dandenney/pen/3/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:escape_attrs` option](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options) to control whether HTML sensitive characters in attributes are escaped:

```ruby
require 'haml'

haml = "%a(href='/posts' data-icon=\"&#x0026\" aria-hidden='true')"

puts Haml::Engine.new(haml, :escape_attrs => false).to_html
```

Output:

```html
<a aria-hidden='true' data-icon='&#x0026' href='/posts'></a>
```

Note that this will apply to all attributes in your Haml template.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in approving this. I'm a noob to Haml and I wasn't using it in a Rails environment so I had to track down how to make this work. It is a good workaround, so thank you very much!

Comment: how would you do this in rails?

Comment: @janechii put `Haml::Template.options[:escape_attrs] = false` in your `environment.rb`. See [the docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options).

Comment: thanks matt, but perhaps I should've been more clear. How can i do this on a case by case basis. I simply want one of my attribute to not escape, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like the top poster's way of completing this question. So far the best way I've found is to do:

```
- foo = "&#x0026".html_safe
%a(href='/posts' data-icon=foo aria-hidden='true')
```

I'm not fully happy with this, but think it's better for rails apps rather than turning off HTML escaping everywhere.

Comment: Just to expand on this - ideally the haml variable wouldn't be inline, you'd hide it off in a view helper or the equivalent depending on what framework/system you're using (eg. Rails/Sinatra etc)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I don't like the idea to disable the feature to escape the characters generally. Maybe you use relay at some point in your application on it.

For me the best way to do it is:

```
%a{ href: '/', 'data-icon' => "&#10000;".html_safe }
```