# Escape attribute value / prevent html sanitization in Haml

Tags: haml

Here is my Haml:

```
%a{:href => "/settings", "data-icon" => "&#9881;"}
```

Which outputs:

```
<a data-icon='&amp;#9881;' href='/settings'>Settings</a>
```

I want to output:

```
<a data-icon='&#9881;' href='/settings'>Settings</a>
```

So I've tried [escaping](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_) the ampersand:

```
%a{:href => "/settings", "data-icon" => "\&#9881;"}
```

But it seems escapes only work for the first character of a line.

I've also tried different methods of interpolation/escaping with no success:

```
"#{"&#9881;"}"
```

Using plain html (`<a href="/settings" data-icon="&#9881">Settings</a>`) is a stopgap measure that I do not consider a solution. What if I want to set the `data-icon` programatically?

Another option is:

```
%a{:href => "#", "data-icon" => "⚙"} Settings
```

But what if I want to use [PUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29#Private_Use_Areas) characters? It also makes it a lot harder to tell what the character is in the markup.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/DkKni)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218025/how-could-i-escape-a-in-haml-so-that-it-compiles-to-instead-of-amp-haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`escape_attrs` option](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#escape_attrs-instance_method) to `false` or `:once`.

```
$ haml --no-escape-attrs
%a{:href => "/settings", "data-icon" => "&#9881;"}
```

output:

```
<a data-icon='&#9881;' href='/settings'></a>
```

`--no-escape-attrs` sets the `escape_attrs` option to `false` from the command line. See [the docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#options) for info on how to set options in other cases.

(It doesn’t look like codepen.io lets you specify Haml options, so I can’t provide a demo there).