# Knockout.js image in Style binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've spent the last hour on this and I know it's going to be something small... I'm trying to embed a background image for a model using a computable (or observable, I feel like I've tried every way) and it either tells me "is not defined" or doesn't compute the value at all. My latest failed attempts and the errors.

View(haml)

no Error, but doesn't render

```
.columns.large-10.background{"data-bind" => "with: currentEvent, style: { backgroundImage}"}
```

error: image is not defined

```
.columns.large-10.background{"data-bind" => "with: currentEvent, style: { backgroundImage: 'url(' + image() + ')' }"}
```

Model

```
    function Item(data) {
        this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
    }

    function Event(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.name, false));
        self.description = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.description, false));
        self.date = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.date, false));
        self.location = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.location, false));
        self.state = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.state, false));
        self.city = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.city, false));
        self.zip = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.zip, false));
        self.allow_guest_create = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.allow_guest_create, false));
        self.host_name = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.host_name, false));
        self.street_address = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.street_address, false));
        self.start_time = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.start_time, false));
        self.end_time = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.end_time, false));
        self.event_type = ko.observable(new EditableText(data.event_type, false));
        self.image = ko.observable(data.image);
        self.backgroundImage = ko.computed(function() {
            return { "backgroundImage": 'url('+self.image+')' };
        }, self);
        self.bgImageUrlStyle = ko.computed(function() {
            return "url(" + self.image() + ")";
        });
        self.edit = function (model) {
            console.log(model.text())
            model.editing(true);
        };
    }

    function EditableText(text, editable) {
        var self = this;
        self.text = ko.observable(text);
        self.editing = ko.observable(false);
    }


    function MasterVM() {
        var self = this;    
        self.newItemName = ko.observable();
        self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.events = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.currentEvent = ko.observable();

        self.addEvent = function(data) { self.events.push(new Event(data));};

        self.removeEvent = function(event) { self.events.remove(event) }

        self.addItem = function() {
            self.items.push(new Item({ name: self.newItemName() }));
            self.newItemName("");
        };

        self.removeItem = function(item) { self.items.destroy(item);};

        self.save = function(data) {
            console.log(ko.toJSON({ event: self }))
            $.ajax("/events", {
                data: ko.toJSON({ event: self }),
                type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(result) { console.log(result) }
            });
        }

        self.getEvent = function(data) {
            $.ajax("/events/", {
                data: { id: 50 },
                type: "get", contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(result) { 
                    console.log(result)
                    self.currentEvent(new Event(result));
                }
            });
        }

        self.getEvent();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `with` binding is on the same element as the `style` binding.

But the `with` only applies to its children so you need to write `currentEvent().` in your style binding to access the properties of your event object:

```
.columns.large-10.background{"data-bind" => "with: currentEvent, 
    style: currentEvent() && currentEvent().backgroundImage"}
```

But in this case you need to handle the case when `currentEvent()` is null and you will have problems with the encoding of `&` ([How could I escape a & in Haml so that it compiles to & instead of &amp;? (Haml noob)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218025/how-could-i-escape-a-in-haml-so-that-it-compiles-to-instead-of-amp-haml))

A more proper solution would be to move the `with` binding outside to your div with using the containerless syntax

```
/ ko with: currentEvent
.columns.large-10.background{"data-bind" => "style: backgroundImage"}
/ /ko
```

Sidenote: you are missing a `()` in your `backgroundImage` computed after self.image:

```
self.backgroundImage = ko.computed(function() {
        return { "backgroundImage": 'url(' + self.image() + ')' };
}, self);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95xGR/).

Comment: I haven't been able to work on this project for a while so please excuse the late response. This is one of the most helpful responses I've received, you clearly know what you're doing. Thank you so much!!!